# InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs' when running on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-8.0

I have a `.net 8` ASP.net Core app in Visual Studio 2022,
if I run it from VS in `IISExpress` or `http` profile it works ok, however if I try to run it using the `IIS` profile, I'll get this error message in the browser:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location
> for package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs'

Answer (score 1):

Add `GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile` setting in you `.csproj` file will fix the issue.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
   
     <PropertyGroup>
       ...
       <GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
     </PropertyGroup>
   
     ...
   
</Project>
```

Comment: tried and I'm not getting that error anymore, even after removing those lines from `.csproj`, but the app still won't start, in the win event viewer I see this message: "
Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/webui' with physical root '..\WebUI\' failed to start process with commandline '"...\WebUI\bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" -argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt' with multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '12449'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:
"

Comment: Hi @buga could you copy the project and delete all the sensitive info and code, then share with us. We need to investigate it.